# PHP Regex to get text inside WP Caption

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have captions in WP that I need to grab the text out of.

Initially, they look like this:

```
[caption id="attachment_16689" align="aligncenter" width="754"]<a href="http://www.site.com/" target="_blank"><img class=" wp-image-16689 " title="Title" src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/image.jpg" alt="" width="754" height="960" /></a> I want to get this text out of here.[/caption]
```

I'm able to strip out the image and a tag with:

```
$c = preg_replace(array("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU"), "", $caption);
```

Which leaves:

```
[caption id="attachment_16689" align="aligncenter" width="754"] I want to get this text out of here.[/caption]
```

I want to be able to get the text out of the caption leaving "I want to get this text out of here.".  I have tried a number of different expressions, none of which I can get to work.  After the above code I have:

```
preg_replace('/(\[caption.*])(.*)(\[/caption\])/', '$1$3', $c);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the text you want to extract always embedded in the same HTML tags, than this would do the job: "</a>(.+)[/caption]"

Comment: I Imagine so, but this client has 1k+ posts so I can't be certain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below, you actually want to replace with the 2nd subject.  Also, you had some mis-escaped backslashes.

```
$caption = '[caption id="attachment_16689" align="aligncenter" width="754"]<a href="http://www.site.com/" target="_blank"><img class=" wp-image-16689 " title="Title" src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/image.jpg" alt="" width="754" height="960" /></a> I want to get this text out of here.[/caption]';

$c = preg_replace(array("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU"), "", $caption);
$c = preg_replace('%(\\[caption.*])(.*)(\\[/caption\\])%', '$2', $c);
```

You could also skinny it down a little more by adding the caption replace into the array.  Just make sure the second argument is an array as well `array('','','$2')`

```
$caption = '[caption id="attachment_16689" align="aligncenter" width="754"]<a href="http://www.site.com/" target="_blank"><img class=" wp-image-16689 " title="Title" src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/image.jpg" alt="" width="754" height="960" /></a> I want to get this text out of here.[/caption]';

$c = preg_replace(array("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU",'%(\\[caption.*])(.*)(\\[/caption\\])%'), array('','','$2'), $caption);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '[caption id="attachment_16689" align="aligncenter" width="754"] I want to get this text out of here.[/caption]';

preg_match("/\[caption.*\](.*?)\[\/caption\]/",$string,$matches);
$caption_text = $matches[1];
echo $caption_text;
```

Comment: Ah that did it.  What was I doing wrong with the preg_replace?

Comment: You didn't escape the first "]", from what i can tell.

Comment: preg_replace('/\[caption .*\](.*)\[\/caption\]/', '$1', $c) could be used as well

Comment: you would still need to escape the brackets, but yes it would